# For sin(1.2) the Error: Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals. follows

Tags: matlab

In Matlab i want to calculate sin(v) for an array v=[0.1, 0.01, 0.001]. But there is a mistake, because inexplicably the sin-function wants the float-numbers with a coma:

```
>> sin(1.2)
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

>> sin(1,2)

ans =
0.93204
```

Why? What happens here? Because the cos works like it should.

```
>> cos(1.2)

ans =
0.36236

>> cos(1,2)
Error using cos
Too many input arguments.
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have a variable name `sin`? Try to do a `clear` first.

Comment: @Susliks can you please accept the answer if it's correct? If not, specify what is wrong with the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Matlab it is possible to declare a variable with the same name as a (built-in) function. E.g. `sin = 1` and this declaration will then have precedence over the original function. Try

```
whos sin
```

or

```
which sin
```

to see if you have a variable called `sin`? If so remove it with

```
clear sin
```

Comment: You should add that a variable must not have the same name as a function in Matlab. This is not entirely obvious.

Comment: Actually that's not a *must not*, but a *can*, since declaring `sin = 1` obviously works...

Comment: I guess that _should never_, is more precise (unless you are absolutely sure that you never will use that particular function). Your example assigning  `sin = 1` does not change that point. In fact, by assigning `sin = 1` you shadows the function sin. This means `sin(2)` will give an error in that particular workspace. Of course you could give the absolute path to the function an it would still work, but imagine the look of that, `longPath\asin(1/(aLongPath\cos(longerPath\myFun(1))))`. I probably missed a lot, but that would not help in justifying the need.

Comment: OK, @patrik, we can agree on that :-) an interesting question would be whether this "unintended feature" can be prevented or warned about somehow?